# Is it possible to record/replay a set of touch events on iPhone for demo purposes?

Tags: iphone, ios, demo, user-interaction

I'm thinking of a way to include a demo of how my iPhone app works along with the app. I need to demonstrate how one of my on-screen GMGridView controls works.

Is it possible to record or programmatically create a set of long press, touches moved, touches ended events and then invoke them on the interface?

Comment: no... I'm pretty that the touch event -(void)touchesBegan and UIGestureRecognizer etc. can only be called when you touch

Comment: if this is for a demo at a show or something, why not make a video, and have hte device play it in full screen.

Comment: This is the tutorial/demo that I plan to include within the app. I've given the app to a few people to test and they did not know how to use that control, so I want add an instructional widget to the app that shows how to use the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this:

1. Add a visual tap effect when you press the screen Record yourself
2. using the App on the simulator using a screen capture Add in a video
3. player at the tutorial screen that shows how to use the app

Or create a UIView animation doing the above steps if you rather not add a video player.

Comment: Of course!  A UIView animation may work. I can create a demo controller and play the animation using that!

Answer (score 1):

A great way to this is SIKULI tool. You can automate the demo work flows easily : http://sikuli.org/